# npm and node commands not found

Tags: node.js, npm, raspbian

I am trying to install Node.js

Originally I tried to install it using `apt-get install ...`.

However I later realised that these were out of date and uninstalled them using:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove node
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
```

I then followed the instructions here:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

which basically says to do the following:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I did this and it seemed to install fine! However the issue I have is the commands `npm` and `node` is not recognised! However the command `nodejs` is recognised.

I checked the directories `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin`, but could not find `node` or `npm`. I did find `nodejs` though.

How do I fix this issue?

The following:
`dpkg-query -s nodejs`

outputs this:

```
Package: nodejs
Status: install ok installed
Priority: extra
Section: web
Installed-Size: 2339
Maintainer: Debian Javascript Maintainers <pkg-javascript-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: armhf
Version: 0.6.19~dfsg1-6
Depends: libc-ares2 (>= 1.7.3), libc6 (>= 2.13-28), libev4 (>= 1:4.04), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.4.0), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1), libstdc++6 (>= 4.3.0), libv8-3.8.9.20, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Breaks: buddycloud-server (<< 0.3.1-2), carto (<< 0.4.6+ds1-2~), coffeescript (<< 1.3.3-3~), node-bones (<< 2.0.1+ds1-3~), node-cli (<< 0.4.4~20120516-1~), node-express (<< 2.5.9-2~), node-get (<< 1.1.5+ds1-2~), node-jake (<< 0.2.32-2~), node-less (<< 1.3.0~20120310-3~), node-mapnik (<< 0.6.7-3~), node-mbtiles (<< 0.2.3-2~), node-optimist (<< 0.3.1-2~), node-semver (<< 1.0.13-2~), node-tilelive (<< 4.2.1-4~), node-uglify (<< 1.2.6-2~), node-vows (<< 0.6.3-2~), npm (<< 1.1.4~dfsg-2~)
Description: Node.js event-based server-side javascript engine
 Node.js is similar in design to and influenced by systems like
 Ruby's Event Machine or Python's Twisted.
 .
 It takes the event model a bit further - it presents the event
 loop as a language construct instead of as a library.
 .
 Node.js is bundled with several useful libraries to handle server tasks :
 System, Events, Standard I/O, Modules, Timers, Child Processes, POSIX,
 HTTP, Multipart Parsing, TCP, DNS, Assert, Path, URL, Query Strings.
Homepage: http://nodejs.org/
```

Answer (score 2):

When I installed nodejs (almost exactly the same way you did,
first the package then the latest version directly), I created
a symbolic link in /usr/bin/node -> /usr/bin/nodejs

```
sudo ln -s nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Eventually I moved node into ~/bin and now run it from there,
since I keep multiple versions installed.

Comment: But what about npm

Comment: npm I installed with `apt-get`, then refreshed with `npm install -g npm`, which let me pick the version to use.  The global install (-g) places modules into ~/lib/node_modules and programs into ~/bin

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg-query -s nodejs` will tell you if the package is installed.

If it's incorrectly installed, remove it:
`apt-get remove --purge nodejs`

Then install it again

```
apt-get update;
apt-get install nodejs;
```

If it's correctly installed you should have the binaries for node and npm.

```
$ which node
/usr/bin/node

$ which npm
/usr/bin/npm
```

Comment: `dpkg-query -S nodejs` just shows me a list of files in `user/share/doc/nodejs/...` and `usr/lib/nodejs` and not much else. I performed the update and did `sudo apt-get install nodejs`, which just said `nodejs is already the newest version`. Both `which node` and `which npm` is empty.

Comment: sorry about that, it was `-s` rather than `-S`, I edited the response.

should include a line saying:
`Status: install ok installed`

Comment: I updated question. And yes it says `install ok installed`